# Global _navigation prop access - v1.x

Tags: react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation v1.x. I like to have a global access to `navigation` prop of a navigator. My hope is that if I do`globalNavigation.addListener()` or `goBack` etc with no arguments, it should be as if I did that from the currently focused screen. I also want to pass it some argument, so that it should be as if I called it rom a certain "key". I use this global from various places (like redux middleware etc).

Would be very useful to also get "getCurrentRouteName" and "getCurrentRouteKey". In pre v1.x I had done custom stuff in routers, and was hoping to avoid that now.

I tried to have a ref to the navigator and use `ref._navigation` for things like `navigate`, `goBack`, etc. I wanted to use it with `addListener`.

Here is how I get and hold the ref:

```
export AppNavigatorUtils = {}

class AppContent extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        AppNavigatorUtils.getNavigation = this.getNavigation;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator ref={this.refNavigator} />
        )
    }

    refNavigator = el => this.navigator = el
    getNavigation = () => this.navigator ? this.navigator._navigation : null
}
```

Doing `AppNavigatorUtils.getNavigation().addListener('didBlur, (e) => console.log('blur from e:', e))` is not working. I expected this to add listener to the currently in focus screen.

Anyone any ideas?